# Error loading package (JNI) - cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy"

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am working on a sample app that I'm trying to modify slightly ([dlib](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app)). The sample uses a C++ library that is called using JNI (its a .so file). The library that comes with the sample works fine. I recompiled that library but now it won't load it, and it throws this error:

```
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy" referenced by "/data/app/com.tzutalin.dlibtest-1/lib/arm/libpeople_det.so"
```

I thought it was a mismatch between the target SDK, so I made sure everything was set to SDK version 24, but I still get this error.

Any ideas? I'm using Android Studio on Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably failed to compile it properly, so the library is not exporting any symbols.  Look at the documentation of your compiler to see what options you need to pass to have it export all the symbols that are meant to be exported.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new BUG in android studio introduced by the brand new Nougat (24) SDK, if you Rollback everything to Marshmallow (23) all will be fine. until the Android Studio Team Fix that.

**Problem**: If you compile With (24) And Targeting (24) and install the apk in a device with (23), the device will not found your library, BUT, if you install the apk in any other device version 2.33 to 5, and 7/Nougat  ( except marshmallow ). all will work fine. TESTED.

**Solution**: Compile With (23) and Targeting (23), and sit down&wait for the Fix. TESTED.

**My Environment**:  i made all Android Studio updates in the last week. ( NDK 13, Nougat and Marshmallow with latest Emulators, and real devices android 4, 5, 6.).

Hope the Android Studio will hear about this problem, because if it is not fixed soon, will be a nightmare in the coming weeks in play store. for the marshmallow users.

**EDIT**:  After upgrading To Android Studio 2.2 (Build #AI-145.3276617 on september 15 2016) the day was released ( September 19 ). i was able to Compile with 24, targeting 24 and running in every device Android Gingerbread To Nougat. both, Emulated and Real.  Just as it should be.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I'm on Android Studio 2.2.2, using SDK API level 25 and a device with Android 6.0.1 (SDK level 23) is crashing on the first native call with the same error.