# Android Fabric distributed debug build: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, dynamic-linking

I've got some native code in my Android app that works perfectly on my device (Samsung Galaxy S3). I've *create a debug built and signed it*, sent the APK to my friend for testing. The app launched on his device (Sony Xperia Z3 Compact), and upon the first call to the native component, it crashed. in Fabric, I see the following stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memclr" referenced by "/data/app/com.myapp.myapp-1/lib/arm/libmyAppNative.so"...
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
       at com.myapp.system.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:9)
       ...
```

Why would the native components fail to run on his device from the same flavor (debug) on Fabric, while it runs perfectly on my device?

Comment: This may be similar to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541599/error-loading-package-jni-cannot-locate-symbol-aeabi-memcpy

Comment: @Bobbake4 I've looked at it. It's actually the same error but the answer tells that it goes away with the update and SDK 24, but I have even higher version than both their Android Studio and SDK but I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was partly due to the linked issue at [Error loading package (JNI) - cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541599/error-loading-package-jni-cannot-locate-symbol-aeabi-memcpy).

The answer there says that the problem only occurs with SDK version 24, which is incorrect in my case. The problem is still persistent with SDK version 25.

I've *solved* the issue by reverting back to SDK version 23. However, this issue is still not fixed and it's a problem with Google's side to fix it as soon as possible.