# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memmove4"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've used NDK cross compiled many different version of library and used them in my Android application. They just work fine, until final release of my app, my fellow worker have tested the application on his `XiaoMi 4` and this error appeared. 
First I thought it maybe because of some particular platform's library's lost, but soon after I extract the `.apk` file and find everything was actually there.

I have searched for google found nothing that can solve the problem.

PS: In my new version of application, I just changed few lines in my C library and all of them is just about `if-else-return` stuff. I'd never used any of those `memcpy-memmove` functions, let alone `memmove4`.

If anyone can explain this to me? what is `__aeaib_memmove4` ?

Comment: And people should always explain for the down vote.

Comment: I would have tried a different ndk version and see if that changes everything. Also, did you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541599/error-loading-package-jni-cannot-locate-symbol-aeabi-memcpy ?

Comment: @yakobom The first thing that came into my mind is: maybe the NDK on my mac is different. So I tried compiling my library on newly installed ubuntu, and windows, no success. The problem just occurs on `XiaoMi4` but works just fine on other devices. So, only explanation is: my current NDK version is too high(and contains some features that `XiaoMi4` doesn't support).

Comment: Compiling your library on a newly installed ubuntu does not say anything regarding the NDK version you have installed on it. As I suggested - if supporting that device as well is important to you, why don't you try an older NDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved the problem by upgrading the APP-PLATFORM in my Android.mk file from 8 to 17, which is my targetSDKversion, so the error is gone.