# How do I set the APP-PLATFORM in Application.mk to match the targetSDKVersion in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to import [Y.C.Tung's AndroidLibSVM](https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSVM) into my project, but when i run the code on my Android 6.0.1 Tablet, i get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy"
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792440/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-cannot-locate-symbol-aeabi-mem) or [this one](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/126) among a few others, the error can be fixed by upgrading the APP-PLATFORM in the NDK's [application.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk)/[android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk) to match the targetSDKversion of the applikation. However, i cannot find these .mk files. They should be

> "in a subdirectory of your project's jni/ directory",

but I don't know where that is as well. This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.krautkremer.nils.mymirror"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

}

I don't know much about the NDK and i'm quite new to Java/Android/Android Studio/Gradle. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're building with CMake, hence there's no Application.mk. [The corresponding CMake argumen](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake)t is `ANDROID_PLATFORM`. According to that page there should be no need for you to specify that argument yourself, but feel free to try it (just don't set it to anything higher than your `minSdkVersion`).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Michael!
How would I do that?
I tried ANDROID_PLATFORM "android-23" inside cmake {} with no success.
Apart from that, do you have any other ideas why i'm getting this error?

Comment: well, right grammar is: arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23" obviously but it didn't work anyway. Still getting that error:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. You NDK API version needs to match your `minSdkVersion`. You app is not guaranteed to run on any release lower than your NDK API version. `externalNativeBuild` handles this automatically. If you need to use API 28 for your NDK libraries, you need to set your `minSdkVersion` to 28.

However, I don't think that's the problem here. This question has come up three times in the last two weeks. It looks like AndroidLibSVM was built against android-24 or higher. As such, it cannot be used on devices older than that API level (all the other questions were trying to use it on android-23).

Comment: Thanks again for your help! So are you suggesting the only solution might be to upgrade my tablet to 24 or higher? I think there‘s a custom ROM for the lenovo Tab10 based on Android N.

Comment: While that would fix the issue, I think the proper fix is to figure out which of these libraries is being built for something higher than android-24. I suspect it's AndroidLibSVM. Check that it is being built for a low enough minSdkVersion to support your device. If that library is using APIs that aren't available until android-24 then yeah, it probably just can't be made to work on your tablet.

Comment: The project runs fine as long as i don't include AndroidLibSVM, so i am pretty sure it is causing these errors, although i still don't understand why. After all, upgrading the device to a custom ROM (Linage OS) based on Android 7.1 indeed solved the problem, so i can die in peace now ;) Thank you Dan!